# Spark structured streaming connection pooling

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

Let's assume that I have a few streams defined like:

```java
Dataset<Row> allMessages = df.select(.....)
Dataset<Row> messagesOfType1 = df.select() //some unique conditions
Dataset<Row> messagesOfType2 = df.select() //some other unique conditions
```

and some logic for processing like:

```java
StreamingQuery firstQuery = messagesOfType1
.writeStream()
.foreach(new CustomForEachWiriter(ConfigurationForType1())) // class that extends ForeachWriter[T] and save data into external RDBMS table
.start();

StreamingQuery secondQuery = messagesOfType2
.writeStream()
.foreach(new CustomForEachWiriter(ConfigurationForType2())) // class that extends ForeachWriter[T] and save data into external RDBMS table (may be even another database than before)
.start();
```

As I mentioned above `CustomForEachWriter` is responsible for message processing and storing into RDBMS. In  the simplest approach I can manage db connection inside dedicated method implemented in [`CustomForEachWriter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/ForeachWriter.html).

But I'm not really fan of this approach so I'm wondering how to introduce connection pooling. Usually Connection and `DataSource` doesn't implement `Serializable` interface so I can't simply pass Connection retrieved from connection pools on driver (exception `TaskNotSerialized` will be thrown). It also looks that when new data arrives new object of `CustomEachWriter` is created.

Could you please explain to me what is the right approach in such cases for structured streaming ?

Thank you

Kind regards

Comment: One thing that I can think of is using Scheduler Pools.

    // Run streaming query1 in scheduler pool1
    spark.sparkContext.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", "pool1")
    df.writeStream.queryName("query1").format("parquet").start(path1)
    
    // Run streaming query2 in scheduler pool2
    spark.sparkContext.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", "pool2")
    df.writeStream.queryName("query2").format("orc").start(path2)